# ClassNotFoundException after adding PullToRefreshListView and packing with ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard, classnotfoundexception

I added the PullToRefreshListView.java source code into my package. The app ran well before I packaged it with progard.cfg, but it went wrong after that operation.

It now throws `ClassNotFoundException` Error.

> 07-19 15:09:14.776: E/AndroidRuntime(585): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.xx.xxx.widget.PullToRefreshListView

This happended after I update my ADT (this ADT can send warn infos in the XML file). It went  well before the update. I tried to update the Android SDK too, but still not working.

I tried adding this PullToRefreshListView widget in the XML file as follows:

```
<com.xx.xxx.widget.PullToRefreshListView
    android:id="@+id/contentFlowList"
    style="@style/pull_refresh_listview_style"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
</com.xx.xxx.widget.PullToRefreshListView>
```

the ADT version20.0.1's requirement is [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).
And I checked nothing's wrong with the environment.

I can directly run the App successfully, but crash happends when jump to the Activity containing PullToRefreshListView after I obfuscated code and packaged it.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your package name is correct?

Comment: of cause "com.xx.xxx" is not my real package name. And I found the  ADT version is 14 before I updated it to 20.And my Eclipse version is Indigo v3.7.2~nothing seems wrong, but..